# How can I make different bots be online during different hours of the day in discord.py rewrite?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am new to discord.py programming and I wanted to make 24 different bots come online in my server at different times for a puzzle. For example: "bot 1" stays online from 00:00 to 01:00 and "bot 2" stays online from 01:00 to 02:00 and so on. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

`commands.Bot` object has attribute `login` and `logout`. So check the time using `tasks.loop` and logout the bot. Then get the current time's bot token and use login(TOKEN) to login again with another bot.

Comment: `logout` function raises an exception `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`. The program would be terminated and the task would be stoped.